# Detecting duplicate binaries in the same directory (Windows)

Tags: windows, file, compare

I have about 30 files in a directory varying from 64KB to 4MB that are BIN files. I need to find if there is duplicate files in there... Many files have the same size.

I would like to find if there are binary identical files in there.

Anyone know a way to do this? I'm under Windows XP Pro.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash them with Md5Deep (or similar), or try a duplicate file checker,

http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?sc=77

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty easy. You can use two nested `for` loops on the commandline:

```
for %x in (*) do @(
    for %y in (*) do @(
        if not "%x"=="%y" @(
            fc /b "%x" "%y" >nul && echo "%x" and "%y" are equal
        )
    )
)
```

If you want to use this in a batch file, you need to double the `%` signs.

The code simply loops twice over all files in the current directory:

```
for %x in (*) do @(
    for %y in (*) do @(
```

then, if the two file names aren't equal (because then we know the files are equal)

```
        if not "%x"=="%y" @(
```

if runs the `fc` utility which compares files

```
            fc "%x" "%y" >nul && echo "%x" and "%y" are equal
```

If `fc` had an exit code of `0` it means that the files were equal (thus duplicates) and in that case the `echo` after the `&&` is triggered. `&&` means “Just execute the following command if the previous one exited with a `0` exit code”.

And for 30 files this is certainly fast enough. I once implemented something more elaborate in batch, but this should suffice.

**ETA:** Found the other batch; still nowhere publicly explained but I once [posted it at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/8223/duplicate-file-finder/8251#8251).

Comment: I think you need fc /b since the files are binary.

Comment: Ah, thanks Larry. My original batch had that already. However, `fc` seems to compare files without that switch just fine. There seems to be some auto-detection going on.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would sort the files by file size first.  Files of different file size cannot the same from a binary comparison.

Those that are of the same file-size could potentially be the same, so I would then generate a hash of the files contents (either MD5, SHA1 etc.).  Those files that have the same hash result are identical.

And to keep everything "on-topic" from a programming perspective (otherwise this question is perhaps more suited to superuser.com), here is a C# project that implements a "shell extension" (i.e. additional items in Windows Explorer's context menu) that will compute various hashes of files selected within Windows Explorer:

[File Hash Generator Shell Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/FileHashShellExtension.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Generate a hash (Md5 or sha1) of each file and compare.

Obviously if two files are a different size then you can discount it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify, how this should happen. Maybe this is a question which belongs to superuser.com, but you may use a tool like [WinMerge](http://www.winmerge.org).

If you have to do this by code, you could calculate a hash value of the files and compare this hash value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fc or [fciv](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) (for checksum)

Or you could download [GNU utilities](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html)

get Textutils which contains md5sum and coreutils, which contains sort /uniq. then do this

```
C:\files>md5sum * | sort | uniq -d -w 32
6f2b448730d23fe68876db87f1ddc143 *file.txt
```

To iterate and do something to the results, use a for loop